# Why I parse json into a Java List, but not a Scala List?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, jackson

I am attempting to parse a json object that contains a list. I am able to parse the list if the field is backed by a Java List, but it fails if the field is backed by a Scala list. What is the difference between parsing into a Scala List vs a Java List, and what do I have to change to be able to parse this into a Scala List?

```
object JsonParsingExample extends App {
  val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()

  // This line succeeds. 
  objectMapper.readValue("""{"list": ["a","b"]}""", classOf[JavaList])

  // This line fails.
  objectMapper.readValue("""{"list": ["a","b"]}""", classOf[ScalaList])
}

case class JavaList() {
  @JsonProperty(value = "list")
  var myList: java.util.ArrayList[String] = null
}

case class ScalaList() {
  @JsonProperty(value = "list")
  var myList: List[String] = null
}
```

The error message I receive is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of scala.collection.immutable.List, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

Comment: Try adding this in the beginning: `objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson doesn't know anything about Scala types by default (otherwise it would have to depend on `scala-library`). To teach it, use [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala#usage).

Answer (score 1):

Because the scala.collection.immutable.List is actually an abstract class. Generally when you use List("a", "b", "c") is the object List.apply() which is coming from this line: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L452 and that's actually an inner class (something called scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon).